# What is the fastest way to sort an EF-to-Linq query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, database-performance

Using Entity Framework, in theory which is faster:

```
// (1) sort then select/project
// in db, for entire table
var results = someQuery
              .OrderBy(q => q.FieldA)
              .Select(q => new { q.FieldA, q.FieldB })
              .ToDictionary(q => q.FieldA, q => q.FieldB);
```

or

```
// (2) select/project then sort
// in db, on a smaller data set
var results = someQuery
              .Select(q => new { q.FieldA, q.FieldB })
              .OrderBy(q => q.FieldA)
              .ToDictionary(q => q.FieldA, q => q.FieldB);
```

or

```
// (3) select/project then materialize then sort
// in object space
var results = someQuery
              .Select(q => new { q.FieldA, q.FieldB })
              .ToDictionary(q => q.FieldA, q => q.FieldB)
              .OrderBy(q => q.FieldA);  // -> this won't compile, but you get the question
```

I'm no SQL expert, but it intuitively seems that 2 is faster than 1... is that correct? And how does that compare to 3, because in my experience with EF almost everything is faster when done on the db.

PS I have no perf tools in my environment, and not sure how to test this, hence the question.

Comment: Since Linq uses Deferred Execution, 1 and 2 are equivalent. In 3, you're sorting using Linq to Objects (because you called `ToDictionary()` first, and you're no longer in the realm of `IQueryable`), and sorting will be done in-memory and no `ORDER BY` will be emitted.

Comment: You can test it with timers. Why are you ordering dictionary? First 2 are different type then third...

Comment: @haim770 Yes, but that doesn't address the issue, which is faster in theory, sorting a table, or sorting part of it? It seems intuitive but I've learned that SQL can be unintuitive at times.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri You're right, but it doesn't change the gist of the question. The point is that the sort is done in object space.

Comment: @hbob, There's no way to tell. It depends on many factors (Database indexes, table structure and much more). If you're asking about specific case, you'll have to test it yourself.

Comment: You seem to have a belief that certain patterns of coding will always yield the "best performance" and that you'll be able to find these patterns and blindly apply them in all situations. That is not, unfortunately, how most code works. It's far better to set performance goals, then write *clear*, understandable code, ignoring the goals. Then *measure* the performance. Only if the code isn't performing well should you consider breaking your clear, understandable code. And at the point, you try variations and again *measure* them, to work out what works well in the *current* situation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You don't know me, and no I don't believe that. The pedant answer of "well, I don't know just test it and see" is silly. In life you need some rules of thumb and stick to them, most of the time. And measure and test for edge cases. This seems like an interesting question, and I wanted to get some sort of rule of thumb. I don't measure every line of code unless there's a bottleneck, but it doesn't mean I shouldn't use some best practices at all other times, or I'll end up writing crappy code with lots of bottlenecks.

Comment: No, I don't know you, but I can recognize a phase that happens in most developer's careers where they think that questions like "which of these options is faster?" can have a straightforward answer, when the reality is almost always "it depends, you need to measure it" and also need to make sure that you're actually working in an area where the difference is useful - i.e. if option 1 always takes 10ns less time than option 2, but the calling code always takes 30 seconds to process the result, does it matter?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I remember my microsoft trainings and all answers on all almost all questions started with: "well it depends...". So I absolutely agree with you and the answer to this question would be obviously started with "it depends".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe you're partly right and partly wrong. The philosohpy you espouse is one I've never completely appreciated. I've seen enough junior devs be told to ignore perf until something blows up, then measure, then test, then try different things... to know that it's bad advice, generally. Yes you're right, always test bottlenecks, and yes, don't prematurely optimize. But for Pete's sake, in most cases don't write crappy code - try to stick to best principles and you'll avoid bottlenecks to begin with. :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For example, it's a good rule of thumb that 3 will be slower than 1 and 2. Not always, *but usually*. So don't use approach 3. There, I just saved you some bottlenecks. ...well, maybe. :-)

Comment: But that's why I ask for clear, understandable code first. If 3 was the most *natural* way for you to write a particular piece of code, and the code, overall, was performing adequately, I wouldn't insist that you re-write it as 1 or 2 "for performance".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Of course not, that would be a waste of time. I'm not interested in improving perf arbitrarily, I was interested in - generally - which is a faster retrieval and sorting mechanism. There's no clear answer though, for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is compiling and being executed at the moment you call `ToDictionary`, so both 1 and 2 should be the same and produce the same query: you get a `SELECT FieldA, FieldB FROM table ORDER BY FieldA` in both cases.

Third is different: you first execute the SQL query (without the `ORDER BY` clause), then your sort the returned set in-memory (data is not sorted by the DB provider, but by the client). This might be faster or slower depending on the amount of data, the server's and client's hardware, and how is your database designed (indexes, etc.), the network infrastructure, and so on.

There's no way to tell which one will be faster with the information you provided

PS: this makes no sense as a `Dictionary` doesn't really care about order (I don't think 3 would compile since `Dictionary<>`, if I'm not mistaken, doesn't have `OrderBy`), but change `ToDictionary` to `ToList` and there's your performance answer

Comment: So generally, 3 should be slower than 1 and 2. But in theory which should be faster, 1 or 2? One sorts a table, the other sorts a smaller data set.

Comment: No, actually, for the most common scenarios, 1 and 2 would be faster. Typically a database provider (and server hardware) is generally faster ordering than a client's CPU. But there's no really way to tell.

Both sort a smaller data set... SQL server will "project" (if you want to call it so) before sorting

Comment: Of course it won't compile. Dictionary has `key` and `value` props not `FieldA` :) But it can be ordered...

Comment: Sorry I meant "3 should be slower".

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri being a hash set I don't think ordering would be important at all... but I hadn't really tried :-)

Comment: @hbob yes, 3 *should* be slower, but really, there's no way to tell. It depends on many factors apart from the Linq-To-Entities code

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri It doesn't matter to the question whether it compiles. The issue regards sorting data in db or object space, and the size of the data. :-)

Comment: Not just that the size of the data... what if your SQL server has a extremely slow CPU and hard disk, and the dataset is large, but your client has a last-gen i7 and tons of memory, and the sorting field is not indexed but is instead calculated ad-hoc? Probably the sorting would be faster on the client in this case. It's a extreme case, and not common, but it's "possible". As I said, it depends on many factors. But if you want your answer, unless you are **positive** there will be such as case: use 1 or 2... not 3.

Comment: You're right. What I hate most is when the infrastucture changes without my knowledge, and suddently "good" queries go "rogue". :-)

Comment: @hbob it's generally safe to assume that servers will always be more performant than clients... and if they are not: a server is a single upgrade point for a variable number of clients. If you depend on your client for performance and have 500 clients, that's 500 upgrades you need to do. This is not a dogma, and there are extreme cases all the time, but it's a decent rule of thumb.